# IPC with QSharedMemory and risk if one of process hang

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, ipc

I noticed if one of process is hang, QSharedmemory.Lock() will last forever.

and QT does not provide any method like TryLock(), so for anyreason if a childProcess is dead ,it will result the main process in problem, is there any workaround?

Comment: Please be careful when tagging languages. Qt has definitely **nothing** to do with C. Thanks :) (Also, add some code, preferably a [mcve], deomstrating what you're asking about)

Comment: Could you please notice if my answer helped in any way ? If not, can you provide details needed to help finding a solution ?

Comment: thanks for your reply!  sry I just get back to this website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap all use of QSharedMemory.lock()/unlock() calls in a wrapper object, it would insure the unlock of the shared memory whatever the return path is (exception thrown ...).

For instance :

```
class SharedMemoryLocker {
public:
    SharedMemoryLocker(QSharedMemory & sharedMemory):m_sharedMemoryWrapped(sharedMemory) { m_sharedMemoryWrapped.lock(); }
    ~SharedMemoryLocker() { m_sharedMemoryWrapped.unlock(); }

private:
    QSharedMemory & m_sharedMemoryWrapped;
};
```

And a usage sample is :

```
void f(QSharedMemory & mem) {
    {
        SharedMemoryLocker locker(mem);
        // in this scope the shared memory is locked while no exception, return .. process ends
        // exiting will unlock the shared memory
    } // QSharedMemoryLocker destructor is called here unlocking the shared memory
    // here the shared memory is unlocked
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Not a fan of giving the class the name "QSharedMemoryLocker", which sort of implies it is a Qt provided class, rather than a user provided wrapper class. Another great use for RAII [Resource acquisition is initialization] though.

Comment: You're right, it was only as a sample code idea. Edited ! Thanks

Comment: "If one of process is hang" does not mean that process quits. RAII or not resources released while the process quitting. Hang != Quit.

Comment: Indeed, may be the question should be refined, as later on he speaks of "a childProcess is dead", which my answer was related to. If one process is hang means there is a lock (deadlock?) or other issue, more related to development/design issue. RAII such as the pattern I describe can be used to avoid deadlocks in most cases. If the purpose is related to one process hanging, code sample is needed to investigate.